# Rails 6 Show or Hide a div if the cookie value matches a token in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am building a rails 6 application, and have the requirement that I have to show a banner with a "cookie acceptance".

I have built said banner and when they click the accept button a cookie is created with an "acceptance token", saved to the database and displayed in the cookie.

What I am trying to achieve is to hide that banner if the cookie is present, and the cookie token mates record in the database.

I am stuck on how to call the cookie and match the value against the database. Any assistance here would be great.. cookies are brand new to my world!

***my cookie create method: - WORKS***

```
  def create
    @cookie_acceptance = CookieAcceptance.new(cookie_acceptance_params)
    params[:ip_address] = request.remote_ip

    return unless @cookie_acceptance.save

    cookies[:roadze_cookie_acceptance] = {
      value: @cookie_acceptance.accept_token,
      expires: 1.year.from_now
    }
  end
```

***My banner:***

```
<div class="fixed bottom-0 inset-x-0 pb-2 sm:pb-5" id="cookieBanner">
  <div class="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="p-2 rounded-lg bg-blue-600 shadow-lg sm:p-3">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap">
        <div class="w-0 flex-1 flex items-center">
          <span class="flex p-2 rounded-lg bg-blue-800">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-6 w-6 text-white">
              <i class="far fa-question fa-1x"></i>
            </div>
          </span>
          <p class="ml-3 font-medium text-white truncate">
            <span class="md:hidden">
              This site uses cookies to help your experience.
            </span>
            <span class="hidden md:inline">
              Attention: <span class="logo-font font-bold">roadze<span class="text-xs">.io</span></span> uses cookies to help your overall user experience, and to allow us to offer products specific to your region. <%= link_to "View cookie policy", '#', class: "text-white ml-3 hover:underline" %>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="order-3 mt-2 flex-shrink-0 w-full sm:order-2 sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto">
          <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
            <%= form_for(@cookie_acceptance, remote: true) do |ca| %>
              <%= ca.hidden_field :ip_address, value: params[:ip_address] %>
              <%= ca.submit 'Accept', class: 'flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-blue-600 bg-white hover:text-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline transition ease-in-out duration-150' %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-2 flex-shrink-0 sm:order-3 sm:ml-2">
          <button type="button" class="-mr-1 flex p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:bg-blue-500 transition ease-in-out duration-150" aria-label="Dismiss">
            <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-white" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"/>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you used partial to show cookie acceptance form?

Comment: @AmitPatel yes <%= render 'global/marketing/cookie_banner', cookie_acceptance: at_symbol cookie_acceptance %>

Comment: i added at_symbol as can use 2 of them in one comment ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop rendering the partial itself like below(notice condition at the end)

```
<div>
  ...
  <%= render 'global/marketing/cookie_banner', cookie_acceptance: at_symbol cookie_acceptance if cookie_accepted? %>
  ...
</div>
```

and you should have helper method in `ApplicationHelper` or relevant helper

```rb
def cookie_accepted?
  CookieAcceptance.exists?(accept_token: cookies[:roadze_cookie_acceptance])
end
```

if this check is required in controllers as well, you can move above method from helper to `ApplicationController` and mark this method as [helper_method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method). This way you will be able to use `cookie_accepted?` across views and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

So this may be a bit "hackie", however I achieved my objective by setting the following in my `application_controller`

```
  before_action :validate_cookie_presnece

  def validate_cookie_presnece
    return unless cookies.present?

    @cookie = CookieAcceptance.find_by(accept_token: cookies[:roadze_cookie_acceptance]).present?
  end
```

all seems to be working well!